# Import Error: difficutly importing a class from another file (in the same directory)

Tags: python

I'm trying to import  'class Computer' from p_class.py. They are in the same directory and I there is also a `__init__.py` there to but I am still getting an import error. I've tried a few different ways of writting that I've seen online (and added the `__init__.py` file) but I'm at the edge of my knowledge and can't seem to understand what's wrong with it.

EDIT: error message: 'Unable to import 'p_class''

if from .py_class import Computer:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user_name/Documents/Python/Scripts/game/game.py", line 2, in 
from .p_class import Computer
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

```
import random
from p_class import Computer

player_health = 100
comp_health = 100

def c_moves(n, h1, h2): # pass in player input / comp random number (player input will need int()) /// h = player_health or comp_health
    if n == 1:
        print('... used light attack')
        attack_strength = random.randint(18,25) # get attack strength
        
        
        l = random.randint(1,6)  # check to see if attack lands
        if l == 1:       # attack missed 5 dmg to self
            print('You missed, fell and hit yourself for 5 dmg')
            h1 = h1 - 5
        elif l == 2:
            print('You missed')
        
        elif l in [3, 4, 5, 6]:
            print('Attack landed\nh2 took: {} dmg'.format(attack_strength))

            # check to see if the opposing player gets a retaliation
```

Below is the p_class.py file

```
import random

class Computer:
    def __init__(self, name, health):
        self.name = self.get_name()
        self.health = 100

    def get_name(self):
        n = open('/Users/saeley_07/Documents/Python/Scripts/Pokemon/p_names.txt')

        read_txt = True
        while read_txt:
            line = next(n)
            for num, aline in enumerate(n, 2):
                    
                if random.randrange(num): continue
                line = aline

                if line == "\n" or "":
                    continue
                
                else:
                    read_txt = False
                    return line
        n.close()

# n = Computer.get_name(0)
# print(n)
```

directory structure:

```
Documents
-----Python
-------Python Scripts
----------game
------------main.py
------------p_class.py
```

Comment: Does a relative import work? `from .p_class import Computer`

Comment: No, I've tried that and I an error: 'Attempted relative import beyond top-level package'

Comment: can you add the directory structure of your project to the question?

Comment: Just added it, sorry if its not perfect (I'm still very new to stackoverflow) but the main takeaway that main.py and p_class.py are both within the game directory

Comment: No worries! Thank you for adding that. I'm not able to reproduce this issue when `__init__.py` is present in the `game` directory, are you sure it's in there?

Comment: Yeah it's definitly there. Blank file with the title __init__.py?

Comment: Make sure the file name has two underscores around the `init`, instead of one

Comment: There's defintily two :/

Comment: Can you paste the error text into the question as well?

Comment: what was the error message without the relative import?

Comment: Wasn't one, the code runs (I'm using VS code) but I get an message under the problems tab

Comment: Oh ok so the code works and I can use the class!! not sure why I get the problem message though?